# May DbDataReader.GetValue() return provider-specific data types?

Tags: .net, ado, hana

Can you please tell me if the generic`ADO.NET` interfaces from the `System.Data.Common` are required to return only native `.NET` types? Specifically, I mean the return types of `DbDataReader.GetValue()` and `DbCommand.ExecuteScalar()`.

My problem is that in *SAP HANA ADO.NET Provider* (`Sap.Data.Hana.dll`) those methods sometimes return *HANA*-specific types, such as `HanaDecimal` instead of `System.Decimal`. I understand that, having greater magnitude, `HanaDecimal` may not always be represented as a `Decimal`, but this situation is relatively rare and *ADO* has [special provision](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720160.aspx) for it:

> If your .NET Framework data provider has proprietary types that cannot adequately be exposed as .NET Framework types, you may extend the interfaces to support proprietary types, then add typed accessors for your DataReader that return proprietary types as well. For example, you can add `GetMyStructure`, `GetMyTimeStamp`, and so on. An example of this is the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server, which exposes proprietary types using the System.Data.SqlTypes Namespace. The `SqlDataReader` then exposes those types as `SqlType`s using strongly typed accessor methods. For example: `GetSqlBinary`, `GetSqlDateTime`, `GetSqlDecimal`, and so on.

That is, instead of returning custom data types from the generic methods, they recommend that one implement strongly-typed accessors, and although the *HANA* provider has such accessors, it still returns custom data types in from its weakly-typed accessors.

Futhermore, according to [Data Type Mappings in ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-type-mappings-in-ado-net),

> This means that when a DataAdapter fills a DataTable in a DataSet with values from a data source, the resulting data types of the columns in the DataTable are .NET Framework types, instead of types specific to the .NET Framework data provider that is used to connect to the data source.
>
> Likewise, when a DataReader returns a value from a data source, the resulting value is stored in a local variable that has a .NET Framework type. For both the Fill operations of the DataAdapter and the Get methods of the DataReader, the .NET Framework type is inferred from the value returned from the .NET Framework data provider.

Since `HanaDecimal` is not a .NET Framework type, does not *HANA ADO.NET Provider* violate the general requirements of *ADO.NET*?

Comment: Pretty sure SqlClient *also* takes liberties with this with geo data etc, so... I'd have to conclude "that's probably fine"

Comment: And do they put those non-native types into the `DataTable` as well? Where does *SqlClient* violate this? According to [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings), it does not...